# How to install the "pylint3" package on ubuntu 20.4?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, pylint, yocto-kirkstone

While building the images for a custom SoM using the Yocto BSP source, the pylint3 package is not able to be installed on the Ubuntu 20.04 distribution. The error message displayed is:

E: Unable to locate package pylint3.

I tried to install the pylint3 package using the following links source:

1. https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/pylint3/td-p/1513152
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1009266/pylint3-and-pip3-broken
3. https://linux.debian.user.narkive.com/WB0TCevl/apt-get-fails-to-install-pylint3
4. https://howtoinstall.co/package/pylint3

But I'm still unable to install the package. Could someone please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Install pylint (not pylint3), with pip in a virtualenv (`pip install pylint`) following [pylint's doc](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/installation/command_line_installation.html).

> You can also use conda or your system package manager on debian based
> OS. These package managers lag a little behind as they are maintained
> by a separate entity on a slower release cycle.
>
> conda install pylint
>
> sudo apt-get install pylint

Comment: Hi Pierre.Sassoulas,

I tired that also on my ubuntu 20.04 OS, but still it same error is displaying.

Actually, pylint3 package is must for kirkstone yocto build system.

Comment: What error ? `Unable to locate package pylint3.` ? The name is ``pylint``, pylint 3 feel like a name from 2008 at a time where python 2 was available and needed differentiation.

Comment: I received the error message: `Unable to locate package pylint3`. I then installed the `pylint`package instead of the `pylint3` package, and it installed successfully. Now, I have doubts about whether the `pylint` package will support the Kirkstone Yocto Build system ?

Comment: Whatever doc you read that asked for pylint3 is outdated.

Comment: Anyway, I installed `pylint` , and now it's working fine. **Thanks for helping me out with this issue!**

Comment: Hello, @Pierre.Sassoulas

could you tell me How to deploy the all build direct images into custom directory inside the poky (kirkstone released yocto project).

Give me an Example for deploying images from temp/deploy/../<machine> dir to ../poky/<customdir>.